# How to redirect Laravel route from Javascript file in blade template

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a prescription form and submitted the form using AJAX.

Now I want to automatically redirect to another route from AJAX after the form successfully submitted.

I have tried with several options like

```
window.location.href = "{ url('/show-all-prescription') }"
```

and

```
{{ route('/show-all-prescription')}}
```

**AJAX CODE**

```
jQuery.ajax({
url:"{{ url('/submit_prescription') }}",
type: 'GET',
data: {name: name, age: age, mobile_no: mobile_no},
success:function(msg){

    if(msg>0)
    {

        // window.location.href = "{ url('/show-all-prescription') }";

        {{ route('/show-all-prescription')}}

    }
}
});
```

**And got the error**

> Route [/show-all-prescription] not defined

**route.php**

```
Route::get('/show-all-prescription', 'prescriptionController@show_all_prescription');
```

But not getting the result. Someone Help Please?

Comment: If your JS external loaded or rendered from within a blade template?

Comment: @paskl...within from blade template

Comment: What happens when you create a JS variable and set its value from blade to a route path? Is the JS variable inside the rendered template undefined or is the value correct?

Comment: @paskl...I have updated my code..please check

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In route file

```
Route::get('/show-all-prescription', 'prescriptionController@show_all_prescription')->name('show-all-prescription');
```

Then in blade file ajax request,

```
window.location.href = "{{ route('show-all-prescription')}}";
```

Comment: You can also use the route as suggested in this answer, in your JS file simply add:
`window.location.href = "/show-all-prescription"` 

Similarly, you can pass parameters like this:

`window.location.href = "/show-all-prescription" + perscriptionVariable` 

While updating the route to:
`Route::get('/show-all-prescription/{perscriptionVariable}', 'prescriptionController@show_all_prescription');`